# Shoulders wont rotate correctly (Problem Solved)

Tags: bones

The shoulder wont rotate like in the tutorial video. (link here: https://youtu.be/nK2F-l8Wjbg?t=208 )
How do i fix it.
[image]

Comment: It looks the pivot is the 3D Cursor and it's supposed to be the Median Point. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/pivot_point/index.html

Comment: Thank you It fixed my problem